# How do we show that limit $\frac{x^6-x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})}{x^4}$ as $x$ tends to $0$ does not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How do we show that the limit of $\frac{x^6-x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})}{x^4}$ as $x$ tends to $0$ does not exist? I thought maybe we should consider two sequences that
tend to 0 and show than $f(a_{n})$ and $f(b_{n})$ tend to different limits as n tends to infinity? But I cannot seem to find two sequences.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x):=\frac{x^6-x^2\sin\frac1{x^2}}{x^4}=x^2-\frac1{x^2}\sin\frac1{x^2}$$

Now, for example, choose the sequences

$$x_n=\frac1{\sqrt{2n\pi}}\;,\;\;y_n=\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt{(4n+1)\pi}}$$

Observe that both sequences tend to zero when $\;n\to \infty\;$ , so if the function's limit existed it'd be the same on both sequences, yet:

$$\begin{align}&f(x_n)=\frac1{2\pi n}-2\pi n\sin2\pi n=\frac1{2\pi n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\\{}\\&f(y_n)=\frac2{(4n+1)\pi}-\frac{(4n+1)\pi}2\sin\frac{(4n+1)\pi}2=\frac2{(4n+1)\pi}-\frac{(4n+1)\pi}2\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\end{align}$$

Comment: Do you mean when n tends to infinity? 'Observe that both sequences tend to zero ...'

Comment: Yes, of course: when $\;n\to\infty\;$ ...and sure: both sequences tend to zero. Thanks, edited.

Comment: No problem- thanks for your response. I'm just trying to get my head around the choice for $y_n$

Comment: Oh, that's only for the sine to equal $\;1\;$ .

Comment: could we do it with something like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n +pi/2}}$

Comment: @Anon Sure, but now the sine equals $\;1\;$ or $\;-1\;$ ,  depending on $\;n\;$ . The outcome is the same, but the limit then doesn't exist at all in this case and it can be slightly messier to deal with...but only very, very slightly more.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For what values of $x$ does $\sin \left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ achieves its maximum? Minimum?

(Alternatively, it suffices to prove that, say, the right-handed limit alone doesn't exist; it might be easier to see the limiting behavior by writing $x := \frac{1}{u}$ and considering the limit as $u \to +\infty$.)